# XCode 5 ImageView disappears in ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

I am updating an iPhone app and recently updated my development environment to XCode 5. In doing so, one xib file was modified and I cannot determine how to revert it. The Image View displays properly in iOS 7, but is missing in pre-iOS 7 devices. However, in the same xib file, the same Image View is used on the landscape view, and it looks correct. I cannot determine why this one Image View disappears only on Portrait view of this one xib file. All others in the project are correct. I appreciate your advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be very very very diffcult to help you without any code samples, settings or screenshots.

Comment: It's probably too late to suggest the use of version control ;-)

Comment: On a more serious note: Try to figure out what went wrong. Start with a NSLog (or a `po imageView` in the debugger if you know how to do that) to see the frame of your imageview. If the frame is correct change the backgroundColor, maybe your problem is in the image loading.

Comment: I had the file backed up from before the XCode 5 upgrade. When I tried to revert to that version, XCode 5 didn't like the file. I guess the files were somehow modified in the upgrade. And I tried changing the Image View to a different image to see if that one would display, but had the same result. NO images in this place are working. I also tried copying the one from the landscape view to the portrait view, and that didn't work either. It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with the image view in auto layout. I'd suggest you go to auto layout on the nib file inspector and turn it off. This should allow you to see the view in portrait mode. You can reenable later if needed. Once auto layout is off try configuring the view with springs and struts. Please advise if this doesn't resolve your issue.

**High-level Concepts**

The fact that the image view is visible in one orientation but not another indicates that the issue you are seeing deals with positioning the image view correct. Two main areas cover positioning of controls in Xcode 5. Either auto layout (which requires creation of constraints in the four cardinal directions) or "springs and struts" (aka auto sizing). I've given a brief explanation below.

**Embedded Image View**

You have an image view within a nib file (auto layout works the same on storyboards just applies to multiple views)

[image: Imageview within the UIView]

**Autolayout and Compatibility**

You've ensured that auto layout is disabled.

[image: Auto-layout disabled]

**Springs and Struts**

Springs and struts manages the auto sizing behavior of the image view within the view.

Clicking on the red lines in the auto-sizing window (within the size inspector) changes behavior of the image view in different rotations. Essentially this manages how the image view appears when the phone is in portrait or landscape mode.

Clicking the outside boundary lines will make the image view hug to the edges. Clicking the internal vertical or horizontal arrows will force the image view to expand and fill the applicable area in both directions. The behaviors will be illustrated by the big red rectangle (image below).

Note: You can add a numerical values to the delta fields if you need to compress, expand or change the placement of the image view on iOS6 devices.

[image: Springs and struts]

**References**

- [Tutorial on Springs/Struts vs AutoLayout](http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2012/12/10/tutorial-ios-6-auto-layout-versus-springs-and-struts.aspx).
- [Apple's Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Auto layout is not enabled on the nib file inspector. The image is visible in iOS 7, but not earlier versions. I am not familiar with springs and struts. Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: @lilmmd - I've added two key references that I hope will help. As noted earlier the description of the problem appears to indicate a problem in layout rather than the image view simply disappearing. Let me know if any of these references help or if you've resolved the issue.